# NoClassDefFoundError with sbt and scala.swing

Tags: swing, scala, sbt, classpath

I'm new to JVM land so I apologize if this is a common problem. I'm using Scala (2.12) with sbt 0.13.13 on OSX.

I'm working on a tiny app that depends on the GUI library `scala.swing` (2.10.x). I ran into a runtime issue almost immediately with example code (http://otfried.org/scala/index_28.html).

Specifically, when invoking `sbt run` I get a stacktrace leading with:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Proxy$class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Proxy$class
    at scala.swing.Window.<init>(Window.scala:25)
    at scala.swing.Frame.<init>(RichWindow.scala:75)
    at scala.swing.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.scala:19)
```

(`Proxy` appears to be a class/trait in the scala stdlib)

Reading on SO and elsewhere suggests this kind of exception is typically emitted when code present at compile time cannot be located subsequently at runtime. Indeed, the code compiles just fine, it is only when running the code that the problem occurs.

All suggestions I've found are to reconcile your `classpath` to resolve these issues. However, if the `sbt` console is to believed, my compile-time and run-time classpaths are identical:

```
> show compile:fullClasspath
[info] * Attributed(/Users/chris/Projects/thing2/target/scala-2.12/classes)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/chris/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.1.jar)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/chris/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-swing/jars/scala-swing-2.10.6.jar)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 24, 2016 7:01:15 PM
> show runtime:fullClasspath
[info] * Attributed(/Users/chris/Projects/thing2/target/scala-2.12/classes)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/chris/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.1.jar)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/chris/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-swing/jars/scala-swing-2.10.6.jar)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 24, 2016 7:01:19 PM
```

So, I find myself at a bit of a forensic impasse. Any suggestions on where to look next would be much appreciated. For clarity, this has only happened with `scala.swing` thus far. I have a couple other small projects in Scala that haven't had any issues. What's perplexing is the "missing" class seems to be scala standard lib material.

Comment: If you are trying to use the 2.10.x version of `scala.swing` with Scala 2.12 then the problem is probably because of incompatible versions. Use the 2.12 version of `scala.swing`

Comment: I think most Scala libs are not backward or forward compatible

Comment: The 2.10.x refers to the internal versioning of `scala.swing`, I think. The docs at https://github.com/scala/scala-swing indicate the swing 2.x branch is the correct one to use for scala 2.12

Comment: Looking at that page it says 'latest release for 2.11', could you try your program with Scala 2.11 just to see if it works?

Comment: I struggled against it for a while and ended up just switching to: http://www.scalafx.org/

Comment: Please check the answer below, version compatibility is pretty important in Scala

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` points to a problem where you mix libraries that were compiled for different major Scala versions. If you use Scala 2.12, you must also use the Swing module with a matching version. Before Scala 2.11, Swing has been published with an artifact like this:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % scalaVersion.value
```

It was then moved to the `org.scala-lang.modules` group. Your build file should contain something like this:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "2.0.0-M2"
```

(it seems the latest Scala 2.11 compatible version `"1.0.2"` has not been published for Scala 2.12, and so you need to jump straight to `"2.0.0-M2"` which should be mostly source compatible).

Comment: I neglected to specify in my original question that I have the correct swing branch specified in my `built.sbt` for Scala 2.12. (swing specified at 2.10+)

Comment: There is no 2.10+ that is correct for Scala 2.12. You are mixing it up with 2.0.x branch for which I have given the artifact above.