# NoClassDefFoundError when running a Scala/Swing program with sbt

Tags: scala, swing, sbt, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to compile an old school project from around March, 2015. I haven’t touched it since then. The project is written in Scala with the Swing library, and the build tool is `sbt`.

Apparently my `build.sbt` file needs updating. After digging the Internet, I found that this configuration should work.

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file (".")).
settings (
    name := "MyProgram",
    /* FORMERLY: */
    //libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10+",
    //ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }
    /* NOW: */
    scalaVersion := "2.13.0",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "2.1.1"
)
```

The trick would be to use compatible versions of Scala and Swing. I tried the following pairs, which I expected to work together (either because I saw them on the [webpage of package Swing](https://index.scala-lang.org/scala/scala-swing/scala-swing), or because it worked for [other people on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41321501)):

- (Scala 2.13.0, Swing 2.1.1)
- (Scala 2.12.6, Swing 2.1.1)
- (Scala 2.12.1, Swing 2.0.0-M)
- (Scala 2.11.1, Swing 1.0.2)

I also tried switching from Java 12 (`jdk-openjdk 12.0.2.u10-1`) to Java 8 (`jdk8-openjdk 8.u222-2`).

However, all combinations give the same error. Compiling (`sbt compile`) works fine, but running the application (`sbt run`) results in a bunch of `NoClassDefFoundError` / `ClassNotFoundException` errors:

```
$ sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /home/me/MyProject/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to MyProject (in build file:/home/me/MyProject/)
[info] Compiling 22 Scala sources to /home/me/MyProject/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[warn] there were four deprecation warnings (since 2.12.0); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] running Main.Main 
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/swing/event/WindowOpened
[error]     at scala.swing.Window$$anon$1.windowOpened(Window.scala:80)
...
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.swing.event.WindowOpened
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
...
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/swing/event/WindowActivated
[error]     at scala.swing.Window$$anon$1.windowActivated(Window.scala:74)
...
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.swing.event.WindowActivated
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
...
```

The application’s main window shows up but is pretty unusable, with every GUI element generating more errors when activated; even trying to close the window *via* the window manager fails.

What is missing to run this program?

Comment: The uptick in frequency of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=NoClassDefFoundError%20%5bscala%5d) is puzzling. I don't have an answer, but maybe those more recent posts will shed some light.